# How to find an appropriate frequent flyer program?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, loyalty-programs, swiss, aeroflot

In the last months I flew a lot with different airlines, mainly Swiss, AirBaltic, Aeroflot and AeroSvit. Now I was wondering if there is a frequent flyer program covering as much as possible of these airlines. How can I find such a program?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are currently three main [airline alliances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_alliance), [Star Alliance](http://www.staralliance.com/en/), [SkyTeam](http://www.skyteam.com/) and [OneWorld](http://fr.oneworld.com/enfr/).

Wikipedia provides a pretty good [overview of carriers to alliances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_alliance) to save you having to check each alliance's website in turn. Have a look through that and see which one you've mostly been hitting.

Also, be aware that carriers sometimes enter, leave or change alliances. This tends not to happen too often, but it does occur (just see the former and future members section on the wikipedia page for an idea), so you can't be certain that an airline (especially a smaller one) will always be in the alliance it's in today.

Finally, be aware that you often have a fairly short period of time to register flights with a frequent traveller program after flying, usually a few months. Unless you've flown very recently, you may find that not all of your flights can be credited when you join a program.

Comment: For your case, Swiss is Star Alliance, Baltic looks un-aligned, Aeroflot is SkyTeam and AeroSvit looks un-aligned. I fear this means you'll need to join each program individually, and then quite likely not end up with enough miles in any one program to do much with it...

Comment: This is also why they're called loyalty programs. OP, you're not being loyal (-:

Comment: Be aware that even once you've picked an alliance, you shouldn't just pick any airline within that alliance - pick the one you fly with most (preferably one based in your home country). Airlines sometimes treat their own frequent fliers a little better (home-airline-only upgrades, for example), and some offers can be restricted to residents of the airline's home country.

Comment: Airlines can also [disappear entirely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerosvit_Airlines)…

Answer (score 4):

Aeroflot has only one [frequent flyer program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroflot#Frequent_flyer_program) - you spend money on Mastercard, and you gather the miles. At the some moment you decide to get your ticket, you are happy, and the cycle repeats.

As Gagravarr said, Aeroflot is a SkyTeam member, and [officially not permits](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C0%FD%F0%EE%F4%EB%EE%F2_%C1%EE%ED%F3%F1#.D0.9D.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.80_.D0.BC.D0.B8.D0.BB.D1.8C) the exchange of the bonus miles from other companies not from SkyTeam.